# Union dict in python

Tags: python

I would like to concatenate multiple dict for the return of my function.

```
def get_params(request, active_id):

    tab_parameters = [
        shadow(active_id),
        light_parameter(active_id)
    ]

    parameters = {
        'id': active_id,
        'parameters': tab_parameters
    }

    return response.HttpResponse(json.dumps(parameters), 'application/json')


def light_parameter(active_id):
    active_lights = LightParameter.objects.filter(id=active_id).all()

    list_parameters = []
    for active_light in active_lights:
        list_parameters.append({
                'name': 'light',
                'color': active_light.color,
        })

    return list_parameters
```

The expected result is :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "shadow"
        },
        {
            "color": 1, 
            "name": "light"
        },
        {
            "color": 2, 
            "name": "light"
        }
}
```

My actual result is (with []) :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "shadow"
        },
        [
            {
                "color": 1, 
                "name": "light"
            },
            {
                "color": 2, 
                "name": "light"
            }
        ]
}
```

Any idea ? I already tried to use union, update, concatenation but without success..

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really involve `dict`s. You just need to correctly merge the lists that make up `tab_parameters`.

```
tab_parameters = [shadow(active_id)] + light_parameter(active_id)
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot :)